# Electrically control material to channel light from specific angle

Tags: control, materials

I am wondering if there is any material that can be electrically controlled
so that light from a specific angle or diretion is received.

Is it possible to manufacture such materials using semi-conductor
manufacturing processes?

Comment: Does it count if the light is reflected somewhere specific?

Comment: Acousto optic modultaor ?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acousto-optic_modulator

Comment: No. But I don't want to reflect light, I want to channel it, meaning that light comes in from a desired and specified direction, which is programmatically controlled. No mirrors involved, I need something more like a tube rather than a mirror.

Comment: So then put a tube on a couple of voice coils.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold how small is that component? I need something in the dimensions of 2x2mm. It might be bigger, but not too big.

Comment: AOM's are Xtals with RF electrodes.  Here's a picture, http://bec.physics.monash.edu.au/wiki/Main/AcoustoOpticModulators (last time I used one they were bigger.)

Comment: A tiny black hole?

Comment: @geometrikal yes.

Comment: How expensive are the light sensors? Could you use a "compound eye" camera obscura arrangement of multiple light sensors, all illuminated by a single pinhole lens? Each sensor would see light from a different direction.

Comment: A light tracking system? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FaxZ_JfYrV8

Comment: naa not anything like that. It needs to be smaller and with as little moving parts as possible

Answer (score 2):

[DLP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Light_Processing) does something like that, using an array of micro-mirrors made with semiconductor (MEMS) processing techniques, but it only has two two stable directions. Possibly a combination of static optics and a micro-mirror array could be used for whatever it is you have in mind. Here is a [TI datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dlp3010.pdf).

[image]

Comment: But don't expect cheap.

Comment: thanks. but I need the opposite. I need to control light that is going to be absorbed, not reflected. It other words I need to channel the light so that the sensor sees light from a specific direction. I need something that does not use motors as the whole assembly needs to be as solid-state and small as possible. if that makes any sense. but thanks for the info above, I learned something new.

Comment: Servo galvo then, maybe, but it's not solid-state.

Comment: what about liquid crystals that arrange in a way so that light is refracted in a controlled manner, does that exist?

Comment: Sort of.  See LCoS.  Since it's built on silicon, it's not transparent.  However, the idea is to build a 'phase shift gradient' in two dimensions with nano-scale pixels so it acts like a phased array.  By varying the phase shifts on each pixel, you can change the angle at which light is reflected without any moving parts.  These are being considered as a component for building fast wavelength selective switches.

Answer (score 1):

Use of polarisers plus a Pockel Cell or Kerr Cell or liquid crystal materials may allow what you want. A Pockel cell uses material which changes optical rotation angle linearly with increasing applied electric field while  akerr cell responds to filed squared.

What sharpness of cutoff do you require.

[Pockel pictures](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=pockel+cell&biw=2560&bih=1376&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=_JRqVMreBYPBmAW_5YD4Dg&sqi=2&ved=0CEEQsAQ&dpr=0.75)

[Wikipedia - Pockels effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pockels_effect)

[Pockels primer](http://www.fastpulse.com/pdf/pcp.pdf)

[Tutorial - 1986 but looks OK](http://www.fastpulse.com/pdf/eodir.pdf)

[Wikipedi - Kerr effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_effect)

Related:

http://fastpulse.com/pdf/pcp.pdf

Comment: What kind of "direction" are we talking about here? I am thinking of direction as if the light is coming from the left side, right side, top, bottom, straight forward or anything in between. It doesn't have to have full 180 degree field of view. I think you are talking about rotational direction.

Answer (score 1):

What about doing something similar to optical image stabilization where a lens is moved laterally to compensate for rotation?  With the correct elements, it should be possible to get a decent range.

Another option is some sort of optical phased array.  If you only need one dimension, then you could build an array of waveguides, each with a phase shifter, then combine all of the outputs at the detector.  Adjusting the phase shift offsets will change the receive direction.  Probably not very much fun to build, though.  Another option might be some sort of phase shift MEMS or phase shift liquid crystal (LCoS) to generate a phase gradient in two dimensions.  These techniques are both rather experimental at this point.  They are also narrow band.

Answer (score 0):

A pair or trio of servo motors and a light sensor with a tunnel/light blocker can work. One controlling each axis. Think motorized mirrors on a car. With micro-servos or actuators (solenoids) it can be pretty compact. Not solid state, but your question is pretty sparse with details.

Comment: Use it in combine with an optical mouse relevant hardware